# windows 7 installation ... no graphics

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, graphics-card

I try to install windows 7 from dvd.
I formatted my pc during install, aftwerwards during install, pc reboots and gives me a black screen. 
i reset, go to safemode to remove the graphics driver,  but there i get the message "install cannot continue in safemode" and reboots to normal mode, giving me black screen again.

How to get windows 7 on my machine?

(latest nvidia driver didn't work on vista either after a windows update a couple of months ago (fixed graphics in safemode: removing the driver))

thanks for help

Comment: Can you try continue your installation with another VGA card?

Comment: Did you try installing Windows more than once?

Comment: don't have another vga card or onboard video at hand.   just tried it once... would it behave differently next time?

Comment: You are going to need to remove the nvidia driver to resolve this problem.

Comment: that's why i tried going to safemode... but that didn't work. even safemode with command prompt doesn't work. always goes back to normal boot=> blank screen

Comment: @Sotto - I took the error message as you were able to boot into Safe Mode but you were unable to run the uninstaller while in Safe Mode. **Please confirm thats the problem.**

Comment: @Ramhound - no, the installation of windows has not yet finished and pc won't finish booting in safe mode. Windows says, before showing a desktop: "install cannot continue in safemode"

Comment: @Sotto - This means your installation is corrupt and its unlikely it can be recovered at this point.  When a fully installed copy of Windows presents that message it means the installation is corrupt.